# How to show an unauthorized view at the requested URL in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, routes, aurelia

If inside of an Aurelia `canActivate` method, it is determined the user should not be able to view the requested page. How do I show an "Unauthorized" page to that user, at the URL they are not allowed to reach?

I do not want to return a `new Redirect("#/unauthorized")` because then the user can't see which URL they are not allowed to visit and I have some navigation bar state in the URL that would be lost.

Note: A possible answer might be, "You are doing this all wrong". :)

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't just save the data from the URL, and then display that info in the unauthorized page? It seems you could also save what-ever state is in the url to use later.

Comment: We have navbar components that get their state from the URL so we don't want to change the URL and lose that navbar state. If the URL does not change then the navbar maintains its state, thus the user can use it to quickly move on from the unauthorized page.

Comment: But can't you modify it so that the navbar state is bound to a property of the ViewModel instead of the URL?  Then it would not matter if the URL was changed.  It just seems kind of fragile to have the navbar bound directly to the URL.

Comment: Yes, but to me it is more fragile to maintain that piece of state in two places because then they could get out of sync. It would be bad for the URL to say you are in "Company A" but the navbar to say you are in "Company B".

Comment: Ok, just a suggestion. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show an unauthorized page without the URL changing. So if the user visits "/restricted-page" and they're not allowed to see it, show an unauthorized template instead of the actual page.

To accomplish that, you can set a template value on the ViewModel itself from within the `canActivate` method if the user doesn't pass the appropriate checks. Then within the `getViewStrategy` on your ViewModel you will check if this value has been set and display that View or if not, then display your regular View.

```
export class ViewModel {
  viewTemplate = "./view-model.html";

  canActivate(params, routeConfig) {
    if (!canViewPage) {
      this.viewTemplate = "./401-unauthorized.html";
    }
  }

  getViewStrategy() {
    return this.viewTemplate;
  }  
}
```

To simplify this further you can just set the `getViewStrategy` function itself from inside of `canActivate`.

```
export class ViewModel {
  canActivate(params, routeConfig) {
    if (!canViewPage) {
      this.getViewStrategy = function() { return "./401-unauthorized.html"; };
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I understand the authorization pipeline but our application has very complex and case-by-case authorization requirements. We want to put that stuff in each `canActivate` method so that it does not all get thrown into a gigantic pipeline step.

As I said, I do not want to redirect.

Can you elaborate on why this is all wrong? What is `canActivate` for if not this?

Comment: Sorry. I read your question too quickly. Please see the latest edit I have added in. I believe this can be done with getViewStrategy within your ViewModel.

Comment: In this specific case you wouldn't need canActivate at all because its always true. So just implement the getViewStrategy hook and do the conditional check plus return of the unauth page over there